# Slow query when use order by with limit 1

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, query-performance

I have a table in mysql with over 80M records. In MYISAM engine.

When I run this query

```
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE (key1=-5) AND key2=467476  ORDER BY id  DESC LIMIT 1
```

query is slow and after 5 minutes I must kill query to release table.

But when i just increase limit size this query work successfully in 44ms

For example (I just increase limit size):

```
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE (key1=-5) AND key2=467476  ORDER BY id  DESC LIMIT 2
```

Now to solve this issue i try the following query and this work successfully (this is temporary solution)

```
 SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE (key1=-5) AND key2=467476  ORDER BY id  DESC LIMIT 2) AS tbl ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

> Note
>   : id is primary and auto increment !

Update:

> key1 ==> folder_id
>
> key2 ==> userid

```
 CREATE TABLE `bm60_mails` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `betreff` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `von` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `an` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `cc` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `body` longtext NOT NULL,
  `folder` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `datum` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `trashstamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `priority` enum('low','normal','high') NOT NULL,
  `fetched` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `msg_id` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `virnam` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `trained` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `refs` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `flags` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `size` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `color` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `mailUser` (`userid`),
  KEY `mailFlags` (`flags`),
  KEY `mailFolder` (`folder`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=95953499 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Are `key1` and `key2` indexed ?

Comment: Not sure about the `LIMIT` issue, perhaps `LIMIT 1` requires that the entire table be sorted, whereas a higher number could be a partial sort.  Question: Do you have any indices on `key1` or `key2`?  Maybe we can speed up your query regardless of which one you use.

Comment: Please submit a explain of both queries. This is rather interesting.

Comment: Questions about query performance ALWAYS require CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, as well as the EXPLAIN for the query.

Comment: whats the reason for putting the where into brackets ? and the AND clause without bracket

Comment: Interesting. What version of MySQL? Please read this paying particular attention to the section on query performance. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ and [edit] your question to provide more details.

Comment: @sagi yes this fields is index !

Comment: Can you post the index? The fact that an index exists doesn't mean it will be used .

Comment: @AmirMohsen could you please provide us the explain output of your query ?

Comment: update and add table structure

Comment: @Noob this is only return the last user email id in specific folder

Comment: please use explain and then your query this will provide us more information if index is used or not etc.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect if you create a compound index on `(key1, key2, id)` your problem will vanish.

The `id` column is also included because that's not implicit in MyISAM tables, althought it is in InnoDB tables.

Comment: The question still remains, why does the optimizer behave like this ? Interesting..

Comment: @sagi without additional information about the structure and explain we can only suggest  like 0.Jones told. It could have multiple reasons that is why we can only do suggestions. But from my experience order by and few others are not the best solution for performance queries.

Comment: adding index is very slow and if i want to add new indexes after two days mysql is crashed!

Comment: @AmirMohsen index are not slow if you using it correctly in your case you already created 3 index and one are used in the query. Index create extra overhead if you do not use it correctly

Comment: @Noob my table is very large and adding any particular index may crash my database

Comment: Without any additional information i can not help you anymore. I understand you that your telling me that the database crashes but you already have three index which is a lot for a database with 80mil records. You should decrease your index in your table structure and only use index on queries which are used a lot. But also for this we need extra information. Goodluck

Comment: Time to switch to InnoDB and a newer version. With such you can add indexes without locking the table (which you call incorrectly calling "crashing").  Also, when adding `INDEX(folder, userid, id)`, get rid of `INDEX(folder)`, which will become redundant.